# How to save custom bullet list in Pages

Tags: pages

I have created a custom bullet list style in Pages (5.5.1) which works great within this document. But now I want to have this custom list style as a default option in new Pages documents (Keynote too if possible!). How can I add my custom bullet list to the default bullet style options?

I have tried searching the web, but have only found how to customize, not save bullet styles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Pages version listed, you can not save a global bullet list style as a template, but you can create a document with a custom bullet style and save the *document* as a template